# How to deal with sentence-level parentheses ending equations?

Tags: punctuation, parenthesis

Say you want to make a remark on-the-fly, which involves a formula too big to be put online, but this formula is supposed to end your sentence (as in, for instance, if we let

[image: [\widehat{G_t}(\nu)=e^{-t\Vert\nu\Vert^2}=\left(\frac\pi{t}\right)^{n/2}G_{\pi^2/t}(\nu)\quad).]]

How do you deal with the final parenthesis ? I can't seem to find any harmonious solution, apart from, either, avoiding such phrases altogether, or typing the formula inline. The `\left.{\blahblah}\quad\right)` solution above seems to me as ugly as rejecting the ). to a new line. Is there a commonly accepted practice in this situation ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE!. It is not only the bracket that doesn't look good, but also the fact that the thing is so large that the spacing between the lines becomes different. I personally either write things not in `\displaystyle` or really use a separate equation. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla (this is because \dots $(\pi/t)^{n/2}G_{\pi^2/t}(\nu)\,$).
\end{document}` but different persons have different opinions on this.

Comment: if you did do this use `)` not `\right)` but the rule is simple, just do not do this it will be ugly and confusing whatever you do compared with whatever minor semantic improvement that you get by putting the phrase in parenthesis.

Comment: if you want the parenthesis, set the expression inline it will break after one of the `=` which is not too bad.

Comment: @David Carlisle Ok, thanks. So is it really something of an unspoken rule that displaystyle equations should never end with a punctuation parenthesis ? I've seen posts here and there about the use of other type of grammatical punctuation, but nothing on the use of ) so far

Comment: I have never seen such a thing in any publication (I have never seen a rule either but it looks horrible and would be confusing to any reader) incidentally the image you show is even worse than a normal `)` you seem to have a large one (which would not be caused by the code you show. Questions should almost always have a complete small document that can be used as a test, to avoid such confusion.

Comment: From **How to Write Good**:  "Parenthetical remarks (however relevant) are unnecessary."

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I didn't put a snippet, but the code is the pretty much standard `\left.{\whatever}\quad\right)`. But yes, neither have I already seen such a thing in any publication, so I guess I have my answer now

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have to agree, but it's time-consuming and unproductive when you have to think of syntactical workarounds instead of actually writing

Comment: You might try to think of a word or several that could be added harmlessly after the equation.

Comment: @Noah yes exactly. you showed left.right just round `\quad` but the image clearly indicates you put it round the whole expression (that is the worst possible option, one small `(` and one large `)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, my bad. I thought this was clear from the display. I'm editing

Comment: With this example at least, `(\pi t^{-1})^{n/2}` would allow the parenthesis to be much smaller.  Or even `\pi/t`, as in the subscript.

Answer (score 3):

If you did do this use `)` not `\right)` but the rule is simple, just do not do this!

It will be ugly and confusing whatever you do compared with whatever minor semantic improvement that you get by putting the phrase in parenthesis.

If you have a situation where you really need parens then use inline math, with the parentheses outside the math, in this case it would break after one of the `=` which might be OK, certainly more acceptable than having the `)` in the display.